# how do I find websites using tag search?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have the following `tags` table:

```
web           | tags
------------------------------------------------------------
google.com    | search,google,searchengine,engine,web 
facebook.com  | facebook,social,networking,friends 
youtube.com   | video,youtube,videos,entertainment 
yahoo.com     | yahoo,search,email,news,searchengine
bing.com      | search,searchengine,microsoft,bing,tools
```

What I am trying to achieve is searching by tags to get a list of websites from this table.

If for example some one search by `google.com` then I want to list `yahoo` and `bing` from above sample table.

How can I achieve this with PHP and MySQL? (I have enabled `FULL TEXT SEARCH` for this table)

Comment: While you can use this structure to search by tags, it won't perform optimally because of indexing. Considering normalization!

Comment: +1 to normalization.  It will make your queries easier to read and write, and improve performance as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "if some one search by google.com then I want to list yahoo and bing from above sample table"?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might give you the results you want, but it would be quite slow. Maybe someone else can provide a more efficient solution:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tags AS t1 JOIN tags AS t2
  ON LIST_INTERSECT(t1.tags, t2.tags) != ''
  WHERE t1.web='google.com'
```

And you'll also need this stored function (just copy and paste this code into the mysql client once you've connected to the server and selected your database):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION LIST_INTERSECT(
    list1 VARCHAR(255), list2 VARCHAR(255)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    SET @delim = ',';
    SET @list = list1;
    SET @overlap = '';
    LOOPING: LOOP
        IF (LOCATE(@delim, @list) > 0) THEN
            SET @word = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@list, @delim, 1);
            SET @list = SUBSTR(@list, LOCATE(@delim, @list) + 1);
        ELSE
            SET @word = @list;
            SET @list = NULL;
        END IF;
        IF (CONCAT(',',list2,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',@word,',%')) THEN
            SET @newword = @word;
            IF (@overlap != '') THEN
                SET @newword = CONCAT(',', @word);
            END IF;
            SET @overlap = CONCAT(@overlap, @newword);
        END IF;
        IF (@list IS NULL) THEN
            LEAVE LOOPING;
        END IF;
    END LOOP LOOPING;
    RETURN @overlap;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

(The `DELIMITER` command is to change the statement delimiter from ";" to "$$" and back. You need to do this in order to define [custom functions or procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).)

Essentially this code looks for a site in the `web` column, then it finds all other sites that share its keywords in the `tags` column. Using this, if you search for "google.com", it will also return "bing.com", and "yahoo.com" because all three of those records have "search" and "searchengine" in `tags`.

Comment: how do I store this function??

Comment: @aron n: If you copy and paste everything from `delimiter $$` to `END$$` it should store the function automatically. However, you need to do it from a user with insert privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to have both a web table and tags table with a table linking them both together?

If your structure really can't change then something like `SELECT * FROM web WHERE tags LIKE '%google%'` would work.

Comment: I don't think that query will work. There's no table called `web`, and only the google.com row contains "google" in its `tags` column.

Comment: Oh yes, meant `web` not `tags`. Also see what you mean but I don't think the OP wants to search by `google.com`. Must be a typo? As the OP talks about "searching by tags". Unless of course the OP is trying to imply searching by the tags returned from `google.com`. In which case your very long SQL snippet looks nice :P