# How should I store tags for domain names in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, tags

Lets say google.com has tags called:

```
search,google,searchengine,engine,web
```

Facebook has tags called:

```
facebook,social,networking,friends,community
```

How should I store both the domain and its respective tags in a database?

Comment: Looks like this question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912579/how-do-i-find-websites-using-tag-search  Either you are the same person with a new account, or multiple people are trying to have their homework done for them.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: or they just was hired to the same freelance position ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create 3 tables for store all this stuff:

- `domains: id | name`
- `tags: id | name`
- `domains_tags: tag_id | domain_id`

domains:

```
id | name
------------------
1  | google.com
2  | stackoverflow.com
```

tags:

```
id | name
------------------
1  | web
2  | lol
3  | facepalm.jpg
```

domains_tags:

```
domain_id | tag_id
------------------
1         | 1
1         | 2
2         | 3
```

In this sample there are 2 tags related to `google` domain and one tag related to `SO`

And for each relation you need to add one more record to `domains_tags` that will store relation between domain and particular tag.

This technique is named [Many-To-Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

As proposed in another answer - you can also add additional field to `domains` named `tags` and store tags there separated by comma, but this solution is weird, since you'll get troubles when you'll need to have some analytics/statistics/searches about domains and tags. The only reason to follow this idea is to "cache" current domain's tag list to just display, **as an addition** (not replacement!!) to the solution I've given first.

Comment: That means he has to do a bunch of joins.  While I know this is the "proper" way to do it, it doesn't really make sense for what is essentially a key value database.  This way he would need to 'SELECT t.name FROM tags t, domains d, domain_tags dt, WHERE d.id = dt.domain_id AND dt.tag_id = t.id AND d.name = 'google.com';

Comment: @Nick: do you know that premature optimization is a root of all evil? Until he doesn't experience issues related to database size and/or performance - this solution is rather good. My work database of size 500+Gb has proven that. If you do care of joins, just split query to 3: 1)select domain id 2) select related tags 3) select tags titles. All there queries will be terrible fast.

Comment: Thanks man but how do I recreate existing one to this format??? currently table has got only two columns

Comment: @limo: fetch all the data to php, use `explode()` to split the tags and fill new tables.

Comment: ok will do that way..but can you explain little more about tags and domain tags table?? say some example..how they look like in final result??

Comment: Oh seems little complicated for last table called domain_tags I have no idea how to create this one??...first two tables are ok that can be done.

Comment: @limo: third table contains "references" to first 2 tables.

Comment: @limo: are you kidding? With `INSERT`.

Comment: no no I am talking about references?? that relation like 1,1,2 and 1,2,3 how do I generate this stuff??

Comment: @limo: it is REGULAR ROWS, like any others. domain_id = 1 == google, because google has id = 1 in domains table. %)

Comment: I agree with you..but one thing I cant understand is for example..tags table id 1 and 2 belongs to google.com. so how do I define that in domains_tags table?? I cant do it manually because I have got 400k domains with tags...

Comment: @limo: in first comment to my answer Nick gave a valid query to get all the data.

Comment: you are not getting my point I believe...can you show me a code for how to create 3rd table domains_tags?? I have only doubt about creating hte 3rd table.

Comment: it is not the table but how do you populate it??

Comment: how do you got domain_id 1,1,2 ?? can you show me through a script??

Comment: @limo: `select id from domains where name = 'google'; inset into domains_tags ...`

Comment: yeah I agree that but how does that insert 1,1,2 it should insert 1,2 right??

Comment: @limo: `insert into domains_tags (domain_id, tag_id) values (1,1), (1,2), (2,3);`

Comment: but that is a manual insert how do I do it for 400k domains??

Comment: oh can you show me a complete code only for table domain_tags?? please. this is new to me and I never done this before this why I am totally confused with last part

Comment: @limo: you don't know how to perform insert query?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a very simple table with 2 columns  | Domain | tag |

```
CREATE TABLE tag_table (domain varchar(255), tag varchar (255));
SELECT tag FROM tag_table WHERE domain = 'google.com';
INSERT into tag_table (domain, tag) VALUES ('google.com', 'search');



i.e.
  google.com | search
  google.com | google
  google.com | searchengine
  google.com | engine
  google.com | web
  facebook.com | facebook
  facebook.com | social
  facebook.com | network
  ...
```